# Datos duplicados en consulta ajax con datatable

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente, tengo esta línea de código que al presionar un botón me llamará la función ver_empleados.. pues bien, al pasar por parámetro el ID este generará una consulta la cual me obtendrá ciertos datos.. hasta allí todo perfecto.. una vez que obtiene la consulta y tiene los datos, ésta imprimirá en la datatable rellenando los datos existentes. Perfecto.. ahora el problema, cuando abro el modal varias veces esta data se duplica.. o bien, se mostrará cuantas veces lo abra, es decir, si yo tengo un total de 5 registros al abrir el modal, lo cierro, al volverlo abrir ahora tendré 10. Teniendo esos 5 duplicados y así sucesivamente.. he intentado limpiar la tabla al final de hacer el foreach con $table.row.clear() o $table.empty() pero no funciona, no sé como puedo evitar el duplicado de la información.. teniendo en consideración que según el ID me traerá los datos de un grupo u otro.. por tanto.. no debería aparecerme la data del primer grupo en el segundo grupo.. ni mucho menos duplicarse.

```
function ver_empleados(id)
{
  $('#consultar_modales').modal();
  var $table = $('.d2').DataTable();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'consultar_empleados',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      id_cargo: id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
      response.forEach(function (response, index) { 
      $table.row.add([
          response['cedula'],
          response['nombre_apellido'],
          response['telefono'],
          response['id_cargo'],
          response['id_tienda']
        ]).draw();
      });
    }
  });

}
```

¿Como podría hacer?

Comment: Necesitas destruir la dataTable y definirla en el `success()`

Comment: @alanfcm ¿Quieres decir que haga un $table.destroy() y luego volverla a crear con $table = $('.d2').DataTable();?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se requiere limpiar la tabla cada que vuelves a rellenar la tabla, en tu caso cada que recibas la respuesta de tu petición ajax ahí aplicarle la función clear().draw()

ejemplo:

```
success: function (response) {
      $table.clear().draw();
      response.forEach(function (response, index) { 
      $table.row.add([
          response['cedula'],
          response['nombre_apellido'],
          response['telefono'],
          response['id_cargo'],
          response['id_tienda']
        ]).draw();
      });
    }
```

o puedes aplicarlo $table.clear().draw() antes de realizar la petición, segun sea tu requerimiento

Comment: Esta es la solución, gracias hermano!